# MYSQL select only matched record from two queries(not table) then sort the result by B query

Tags: mysql

guys i have a case like this, i want to eliminate the item in A that are not in B (**see the red blocked item in QUERY A**) so that i will get a result like query C 
but after that i want to sort the item per TID in query C according to the query B

then after it's been sorted it will look like **query c sorted**

let's says for example ACD --> ADC (**see blue blocked item**)
it's sorted according to query B and by transaction

and if item in query A didn't matched at all with query b, i wanted to deleted it completely (**see tid 5**)

here's the ilustration of my query

[image]

please help me solve this, my project has been stucked cause of this ..thx u
regards, me

Comment: what are you sorting by in QueryC-Sorted? that doesn't look like it's sorted by Item?

Comment: oh you're sorting by Frequency!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT A.TID,A.ITEM
FROM (QueryA) A
INNER JOIN (QueryB) B ON (B.ITEM=A.ITEM)
ORDER BY A.TID,B.FREQUENCY DESC
```

this will give you QueryC-Sorted by first TID, then Frequency Descending.

I am assuming you're trying to get to QueryC-Sorted without actually trying to delete rows from QueryA in the database.

as you commented, and seeing your query maybe you can run this one

```
SELECT kode_faktur AS TID, 
       kode_brg AS ITEM, 
   COUNT( kode_brg ) AS support
FROM detail
GROUP BY TID,ITEM
HAVING support >= 100
ORDER BY TID, support DESC
```

if that doesn't give you what you want you can try this one

```
SELECT A.kode_faktur AS TID,A.kode_brg AS ITEM
FROM detail A
INNER JOIN
( SELECT kode_brg AS ITEM, COUNT( kode_brg ) AS support 
  FROM detail GROUP BY kode_brg HAVING support >=100 
)B ON (B.ITEM = A.kode_brg)
ORDER BY A.kode_faktur,B.support DESC
```

Comment: wow you're great bro!! it's worked like a charm!!
but it's running very slow
it's the first time i run a query and it took minutes to complete
is there any way to simplify the query

nb: my database is big(it has 4000++ record)

here is my code

    SELECT A.TID, A.ITEM
    FROM (

    SELECT kode_faktur AS TID, kode_brg AS ITEM
    FROM detail
    )A
    INNER JOIN (

    SELECT kode_brg AS ITEM, COUNT( kode_brg ) AS support
    FROM detail
    GROUP BY kode_brg
    HAVING support >=100
    ORDER BY support DESC
    )B ON ( B.ITEM = A.ITEM )
    ORDER BY A.TID, B.support DESC

Comment: check the bottom of my answer, i just added a query, see if that one runs and return what you want. I am just making a guess as I do not know what your data looks like maybe isn't what you want.

Comment: if that doesn't give you want, i just wrote another query at the bottom of my answer that should give you want, I just made a direct INNER join on the first table A, and took out the inner ORDER BY of queryB as you don't need to order since you're ordering at the end anyways

Comment: if it's still slow you should look into CREATE INDEX on the kode_brg column something like `CREATE INDEX your_index_name ON detail (kode_brg);`

Comment: wow thanks Tin Tran, it runs in a few seconds..
i corrected the last line of your code (ORDER BY A.kode_brg ---> A.kode_faktur)

thank you so much tran, you're very awesome..

Comment: I just noticed that mistake, and made a change in my answer too thanks for noticing that

Comment: So you didn't need to create INDEX? and it sped it up to seconds long now?

Comment: sorry for my late reply, yes it did..i hardly believe that

the first query took me 2minutes 30 seconds to complete with 3 warnings

buat the last query you gave me just took about 2 seconds  

anyway thank you very much Tin Tran, i've stucked on this problem for more than 1 week ^^

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you mean, but I'll try something a hint

ad 1.  i want to eliminate the item in A that are not in B

```
 SELECT * FROM (queryA) as A WHERE item not in (SELECT item FROM queryB)
```

ad 2. it's sorted according to query B and by transaction

imo it's no posible. Add new column with weight of any letter and sort by this new column

ad 3.  and if item in query A didn't matched at all with query b, i wanted to deleted it completely

like 1:

```
 DELETE * FROM (queryA) as A WHERE item not in (SELECT item FROM queryB)
```

Comment: thanks for your help bro
but it 's not like what i want, i do not want delete the rows, sorry for my ambiguos words